# PHP CURL How to filter json results?

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

in need to filter my curl json requests.
My problem is.. my ouput list is allways the complete JSON list (Link 1-3).
I need to request only Link 1 & Link 3.

Please check my filter example

```
$responseData = apiRequest("link/list", array('id' => json_encode(array('1001', '1003'))));
```

This filter does not work for me. How can i solve my problem?
Im happy for every tip

Thanks a lot

Api Request:

```
function apiRequest($command, $requestData = array()) {
            $apiKey = "";
                $headers = array(
     'Authorization: APIKEY '.$apiKey
);
            if (!is_array($requestData)) {
                $requestData=array();
            }
            $requestData['apiKey'] = $apiKey;
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.example.com/'.$command,        
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestData)
                );

            if (($responseData = curl_exec($curl))===false) {
                curl_close($curl);
                /* echo "cURL error: ".curl_error($curl); */
                return null;
            }

            return json_decode($responseData, true);
        }

        $responseData = apiRequest("link/list", array('id' => json_encode(array('1001', '1003'))));
```

Json list:

```
 {
    "count": 3,
    "links": [
        {
            "id": 1001,
            "name": "Link 1",
            "title": "Link Title",
            "head": "Links",
            "pic": "https://image.com/pic.jpg",
            "views": "10,000+",
            "country": "US"
        }

          {
            "id": 1002,
            "name": "Link 2",
            "title": "Link Title 2",
            "head": "Links",
            "pic": "https://image.com/pic.jpg",
            "views": "10,000+",
            "country": "US"
        }

       {
            "id": 1003,
            "name": "Link 3",
            "title": "Link Title 3",
            "head": "Links",
            "pic": "https://image.com/pic.jpg",
            "views": "10,000+",
            "country": "US"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Better to filter out the result while getting it from API end** but If it is not possible to filter out the result on the API then try this way with php `array_filter()`,

```
<?php
$api_response = '{"count":3,"links":[{"id":1001,"name":"Link 1","title":"Link Title","head":"Links","pic":"https://image.com/pic.jpg","views":"10,000+","country":"US"},{"id":1002,"name":"Link 2","title":"Link Title 2","head":"Links","pic":"https://image.com/pic.jpg","views":"10,000+","country":"US"},{"id":1003,"name":"Link 3","title":"Link Title 3","head":"Links","pic":"https://image.com/pic.jpg","views":"10,000+","country":"US"}]}';

$filter = [1001,1003];
$links = json_decode($api_response)->links;
$filtered = array_filter($links, function ($item) use ($filter) {
    return in_array($item->id, $filter);
});

print_r($filtered);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BNotG

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to do it in the api :/ does it even offer that functionality? if so ask them, rtm or give us the real link to the site so we can check the docs..

though if not which I suspect, then simply use [array filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. yes its possible thats this function not exist on this api. i will check out the php array filter